# CRITERIA API get records that are older then 5 days

Tags: java, jpa

I have a query in CRITERIA API that goes like this:

```
CriteriaQuery<Application> query = builder.get().createQuery(Application.class).distinct(true);
Root<Application> root = query.from(Application.class);
root.join(Application_.answerSets).get(AnswerSet_.createDate);
```

I want to get records, where `createDate` is older than 5 days. I have no clue, how to achieve this. I'm really bad with CRITERIA API, but the project I'm working on is using this, so I'm in trouble so far.

Comment: Not familiar with JPA but, Hibernate (compatible with JPA) has `Restrictions` construct to help you limit/filter the records in Criteria query. In this situation `Restricition.gt(< given date>)` should help.

Comment: try `criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get(AnswerSet_.createDate), new Date());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code is an illustration for the suggestion from @Rembo. Notice that the key is on the use of the method ".where(...)"

```
public List<Application> getOlderThanNDays( int days )
{
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Application> cq = cb.createQuery( Application.class );
    Root<Application> root = cq.from( Application.class );

    long today = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long nDays = days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    long nDaysAgo = today - nDays;
    Date nDaysAgoDate = new Date( nDaysAgo );

    // Is here the response to your question?
    cq.where( cb.lessThanOrEqualTo( root.get(Application_.date), nDaysAgoDate ) );

    TypedQuery<Application> q = entityManager.createQuery( cq );

    List<Application> list = q.getResultList();
    return list;
}
```

I'm assuming that you're using the @StaticMetamodel annotation in your class Application_.java, and that the type of the date is java.sql.Date.